# How to get paper size if my printer is TMetafilePrinter?

Tags: delphi, printers, metafile

I try to get width and heigth of page of my TMetfile printer

```
var MFPrinter: TMetaFilePrinter;

MFPrinter := TMetaFilePrinter.Create(nil);

MFPrinter.BeginDoc
DC := MFPrinter.Canvas.Handle;    

W:=GetDeviceCaps(DC,HORZSIZE)
H:=GetDeviceCaps(DC,VERTSIZE);
```

But always I get these results: W=286 and H=503
inappreciable which paper size I use (A3,A4,A5) or page orientation.

I think these dimensions is my screen size instead paper size.

Comment: What *is* a `TMetafilePrinter`? I don't think that is something that comes with Delphi...

Comment: You get the values ​​that your canvas offers regardless of which area you want to use.